# NextJs 13 application keep on refreshing in production (flash)

Tags: next.js13

I have a weird issue.

Two pages keep on reloading fast. It is hard to debug.
It is written in "next": "^13.4.7"

This is the page :

```js
import { push } from "@socialgouv/matomo-next";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";

import { CartSummary, CheckoutLineItem, Layout, Spinner } from "@/components";
import { useRegions } from "@/components/RegionsProvider";
import { BaseSeo } from "@/components/seo/BaseSeo";
import { messages } from "@/components/translations";
import { useCheckout } from "@/lib/providers/CheckoutProvider";

const externalCheckoutBaseUrl =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CHECKOUT_URL;

function Cart() {
  const t = useIntl();
  const { loading, checkoutError, checkout, checkoutToken } = useCheckout();
  const { currentChannel, currentLocale } = useRegions();

  if (checkoutError) return <p>Error</p>;
  if (!checkout && !loading) return <p>Error</p>;

  const isCheckoutLoading = loading || typeof window === "undefined";
  const products = checkout?.lines || [];

  // we rewrite `/checkout` to the checkout domain to keep cookies
  const channelSN = "cfa"
  const externalCheckoutUrl = checkout
    ? `?checkout=${checkout.id}&locale=${currentLocale}&channel=${channelSN}&saleorApiUrl=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI}`
    : "";
  /**
   * Matomo setup
   */
  if (checkout != null) {
    // Order Array - Parameters should be generated dynamically
    push(["trackEcommerceOrder",
      checkout.id, // (Required) orderId
      `${checkout.totalPrice.gross}`, // (Required) grandTotal (revenue)
      `${checkout.subtotalPrice.net}`, // (Optional) subTotal
      `${checkout.subtotalPrice.tax}`, // (optional) tax
      `${checkout.shippingPrice.gross}`, // (optional) shipping
      `${checkout.discount ? checkout.discount.amount : "false"}` // (optional) discount
    ]);
    push(["trackPageView"]);
  }

return (
  <>
    <BaseSeo title="Cart" />

    <div className="grid sm:px-10 lg:grid-cols-2 lg:px-20 xl:px-32">
      <div className="px-4 pt-8">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
          {t.formatMessage(messages.cartPageHeader)}
        </h1>
        <p className="text-gray-400">Vérifiez vos articles.</p>
        {isCheckoutLoading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          products.map((line) => (
            <li key={line?.id} className="flex flex-wrap py-6">
              {line && checkoutToken && <CheckoutLineItem line={line} />}
            </li>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
      {!!checkout && (
        <CartSummary checkout={checkout} checkoutUrl={externalCheckoutBaseUrl + externalCheckoutUrl} />
      )}
    </div>

  </>
);
}

export default Cart;

Cart.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};
```

The component

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";

import { CheckoutDetailsFragment, useCheckoutAddPromoCodeMutation } from "@/saleor/api";

import { useRegions } from "../RegionsProvider";
import { messages } from "../translations";

export interface PromoCodeFormData {
  promoCode: string;
}

export interface CartSummaryProps {
  checkout: CheckoutDetailsFragment
  checkoutUrl: string

}

export function CartSummary({ checkout, checkoutUrl}: CartSummaryProps) {

  const t = useIntl();
  const [editPromoCode] = useState(false);
  const [checkoutAddPromoCodeMutation] = useCheckoutAddPromoCodeMutation();
  const { subtotalPrice, shippingPrice, totalPrice, discount } = checkout;
  const {
    register: registerForm,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmitForm,
    formState: { errors: errorsForm },
    setError: setErrorForm,
  } = useForm<PromoCodeFormData>({});
  const { query, formatPrice } = useRegions();

  const onAddPromoCode = handleSubmitForm(async (formData: PromoCodeFormData) => {
    const { data: promoMutationData } = await checkoutAddPromoCodeMutation({
      variables: {
        promoCode: formData.promoCode,
        token: checkout.token,
        locale: query.locale,
      },
    });
    const errors = promoMutationData?.checkoutAddPromoCode?.errors;
    if (!!errors && errors.length > 0) {
      setErrorForm("promoCode", { message: errors[0].message || "Error" });
    }
  });
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="px-4 pt-8 mt-10 bg-gray-50 lg:mt-0">
        <p className="text-xl font-medium">Détails de commande</p>
        <p className="text-gray-400">Complétez votre commande</p>
          {(editPromoCode || !discount?.amount) && (
            <form className="pb-4" onSubmit={onAddPromoCode}>
              <label htmlFor="discount-code" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                {t.formatMessage(messages.discountCodeFieldLabel)}
              </label>
              <div className="flex mt-1 space-x-4">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="discount-code"
                  className="block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm sm:text-sm"
                  {...registerForm("promoCode", {
                    required: true,
                  })}
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 bg-gray-200 rounded-md hover:bg-primary-300"
                  aria-label="promocode-button"
                >
                  {t.formatMessage(messages.activateButton)}
                </button>
              </div>
              {!!errorsForm.promoCode && (
                <p className="pt-2 text-sm text-red-500">{errorsForm.promoCode?.message}</p>
              )}
            </form>
          )}
          <div className="flow-root">
            <dl className="text-sm">
              {!!discount?.amount && (
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-2">
                  <dt className="text-gray-600">{t.formatMessage(messages.discount)}</dt>
                  <dd className="font-medium text-gray-900">{formatPrice(discount)}</dd>
                </div>
              )}
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-2">
                <dt className="text-gray-600">{t.formatMessage(messages.subtotal)}</dt>
                <dd className="font-medium text-gray-900">{formatPrice(subtotalPrice?.net)}</dd>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-2">
                <dt className="text-gray-600">{t.formatMessage(messages.shipping)}</dt>
                <dd className="font-medium text-gray-900">{formatPrice(shippingPrice?.gross)}</dd>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-2">
                <dt className="text-gray-600">{t.formatMessage(messages.tax)}</dt>
                <dd className="font-medium text-gray-900">{formatPrice(subtotalPrice?.tax)}</dd>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between pt-4 border-t border-gray-300">
                <dt className="text-lg font-bold text-gray-900">{t.formatMessage(messages.total)}</dt>
                <dd className="text-lg font-bold text-gray-900">{formatPrice(totalPrice?.gross)}</dd>
              </div>
            </dl>
          </div>
          <div className="m-12">
            <Link
              href={`${checkoutUrl}`}
              passHref
              className="block w-full px-4 py-3 font-medium text-center text-white border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm bg-primary-400 text-md hover:bg-primary-700"
              >

              {t.formatMessage(messages.checkoutButton)}

            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  );
}
```

This is the [URL](https://www.jokosun.com/sn/cart)

If I rebuild my application locally on my laptop, there is no issue. Steps :

1. Remove all node_modules
2. install all dependencies
3. pnpm run build
4. pnpm run start

On production, this happend in Docker.

Do you have any idea, on how to debug it ? What to look at ?
Please guide me on things you need so I can provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: It works with Firefox. 
It does this with Chrome. It disapear if I clear the cache of my browser. 

Any idea ?